# Canonical bundle formula for CY fibration over $\mathbb P^1$ without multiple fibers

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-varieties

Let us call a smooth projective vartiety $M$ as Calabi-Yau (CY) manifold if it has trivial canonical class and
$h^i(M, \mathcal O_M ) = 0$ for $0 < i < \dim(M)$.
In this definition, a CY 1-fold is an elliptic curve,   a CY 2-fold is a projective $K3$ surface and etc.

Let $\pi: X \rightarrow \mathbb P^1$ be a fibration of a smooth projective variety $X$ of dimension  $n$ whose generic fiber is a CY $(n-1)$-fold and assume that there are no multiple fibers.

For $n=2$, it is known that $K_X = \pi^*( \chi(\mathcal O_X)-2)$.

Is there a similar simple canonical bundle formula for higher $n$?

Comment: Yes. See [A canonical bundle formula](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-differential-geometry/volume-56/issue-1/A-Canonical-Bundle-Formula/10.4310/jdg/1090347529.full) by Fujino and Mori, J. Differential Geom. 56(1): 167-188 (September, 2000).